# What´s the result of this endgame? Black just played f3.

Tags: endgame, pawns

```
[FEN "8/1KP5/8/8/5p2/8/8/6k1 b - - 0 3"]
```

I recently come with this position on one of my games and I would like to know the result of this endgame...

Comment: Old question, but today we have online endgame tablebases: https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=8/1KP5/8/8/8/5p2/8/6k1_w_-_-_0_1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[FEN "8/1KP5/8/8/5p2/8/8/6k1 b - - 0 3"]
[Plycount "19"]

3...f3 ( On a race to promotion ) 4.c8=Q { ...that white just won. Or did he?!? } 4...f2 5.Qg4+ Kh1 6.Qf3+ Kg1 7.Qg3+ Kh1 8.Qh3+ ( 8.Qxf2 { If white takes the pawn...Disaster strikes = STALEMATE !! } ) 8...Kg1 9.Qg4+ Kh1 10.Qf3+ Kg1 11.Qg3+ Kh1
```

*If white takes the pawn...Disaster strikes = STALEMATE !!

If white allows black
to promote the pawn, in order to avoid drawing by repetition, the resulting
one is also a draw as no progress can be made by either side !

Answer (score 2):

The general rule in K+P vs K+Q is that, if the pawn is at the 7th(2nd) row on the third file (`c` or `f` file), and the opponent's king is not near, the game is a Draw because of the stalemate positions.

Comment: @bof I specifically say **on the third file**. Do you read before voting?

Comment: My mistake. Had to make a small edit, or else the system wouldn't let me undo my downvote.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen Seeing as how confusing this came out, your edit appears to be really useful. Thank you.